# Slice doesn't panic on length but it panics while getting value for index equals length

Tags: string, go, indexing

I have a `string`, and when I want to get the value at `i` index it panics, but when I slice out of the same `string` keeping lower index value as length then it doesn't panic. Wanted to know how 1 and 2 differs?

```
func main() {
    str := "a"
    fmt.Println(str[1])  // 1 this panics
    fmt.Println(str[1:]) // 2 this doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR; In an index expression the index must be less than the length, and in a slice expression the length is a valid index.**

In an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) the index must be *in range*, else it panics. The index is in range if `0 <= i < length`. Quoting from the spec:

> In the index expression `a[x]`...
>
> If `a` is not a map:
>
> - the index `x` is in range if `0 <= x < len(a)`, otherwise it is *out of range*

And:

> For a of [string type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types):
>
> - if `x` is out of range at run time, a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) occurs

Your `str` string variable stores a `string` value which has a single byte: `'a'`. Indexing starts at zero, so that single byte has index `0`. Its length is `1`, so there is no element at index `1`.

In a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

> `a[low : high]`
>
> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range.

In a slice expression the length is a valid index. So in your case indexing `str` like `str[1:]` will result in an empty string: `""`:

> In a slice expression `a[low : high]`...
>
> The result has indices starting at `0` and length equal to `high - low`.
>
> A missing `low` index defaults to zero; a missing `high` index defaults to the length of the sliced operand.

So `str[1:]` is the same as `str[1:len(str)]` which is `str[1:1]`. The result string will have a length of `high - low = 1 - 1 = 0`: the empty `string`.